# Strange symbol error in sql query with quotation marks

Tags: sql, r

I have a sql query in my R code:

```
 query <- glue("SELECT
    oper.value
    oper.status
    oper.class
 FROM "uploads".ratings AS rates"
```

But i get this error:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"oper.class
 FROM "uploads"
```

How could i handle it? How should i write schema part in query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that r interprets the double quotes character as the end of the string. You would need to use an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) to your query.

I think this should do it :

```
query <- glue("SELECT
    oper.value
    oper.status
    oper.class
FROM \"uploads\".ratings AS rates")
```